# LINQ to Entitites: How to take all values by a predicate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to get all values that has the same predicate. For example: i have many Packages records that consist of it's own Id, Data and DeviceId which indicates from which device the package has arrived.

Here's the function that I have created which only returns the first package

```
 public Package GetPackageByDeviceId(int id)
    {
        return avldbContext.Packages.Where(p => p.DeviceId == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Any advices on how to get all packages ?

Comment: remove `.FirstOrDefault()` function.

Comment: Don't use `First` if you want more than 1 result. Either return the results directly, load them eagerly with `ToList` or `ToArray` etc. Is there a reason you haven't tried something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<Package> GetPackagesByDeviceId(int id)
{
    return avldbContext.Packages.Where(p => p.DeviceId == id);
}
```

Comment: But is there any other way without changing the Package entity to IEnumerable or to List ? Because i'm using codefirst and it makes things difficult

Comment: @hellodave - sorry, but I don't understand your requirement than, you want to have a list, so naturally your method has to return a list - to be precises a list of packages so `IEnumerable<Package>`, a single package can't contain multiple packages

Answer (score -1):

```
public List<Package> PackagesByDeviceId(int id)
{
    return avldbContext.Packages.Where(p => p.DeviceId == id).ToList();
}
```

First, you need to specify "s" char end of your method. Because the method returns multiple rows. Than without FirstOrDefault(). You need to put a ToList() extension method to pull all records. Good luck.

edit:
By the way, your code looks like still looking for primary key. You need to scale your prediction.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get `IEnumerable` result

```
public IEnumerable<Package> GetPackagesByDeviceId(int id)
{
    return avldbContext.Packages.Where(p => p.DeviceId == id);
}
```

Or if you want to get `List`

```
public List<Package> GetPackagesByDeviceId(int id)
{
    return avldbContext.Packages.Where(p => p.DeviceId == id).ToList();
}
```